# php gettext blank only

Tags: php, gettext

I have confirmed that I have gettext installed on my server. I used [this](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html) tutorial to get started and followed its directions.

I have also read at PHP manual's gettext page on [gettext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) that if a translation is not found in the translation table, it will just use the untranslated text.

For localization, I have

```
$language = "en";
putenv("LANG=$language"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, 'home/www/translations'); 
textdomain($domain);
```

I have two directories set up, one for en (translations/en/LC_MESSAGES/message.po) and another for zh (same structure.) I generated .po files using

```
xgettext -n *.php
```

My problem: No text is displaying at all for "en." The original strings are English, I originally tried to leave out the "en" directory entirely, but that didn't help.

Comment: You should find a different PO reader. Almost all frameworks have one, just get one from there. Bc the builtin gettext reader from PHP is one of the worst pieces of software ever written... Idk what was the developer thinking when he decided to rely on system locale setting..

Comment: Gettext is fine. I am using it regularly and simply works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have english texts in source files, you do not need en version of catalogs. Try to look to logs, text should show up, there will be something wrong. Also try to restart server, catalog are cached.

This is how I am using gettext, tested on windows/linux server:

```
function setLocaleByLang($lang)
{
    bindtextdomain('app', APPDIR . "/locale"); // APPDIR is definded constant including root of application
    bind_textdomain_codeset('app', "UTF-8");
    textdomain('app');

    $map = array(
        'cs' => array('cs_CZ.UTF-8', 'cs_CZ', 'cs', 'czech'),
        'en' => array('en_US.UTF-8', 'en_US', 'en', 'english'),
        'de' => array('de_DE.UTF-8', 'de_DE', 'de', 'german'),
        'pl' => array('pl_PL.UTF-8', 'pl_PL', 'pl', 'polish'),
        'sk' => array('sk_SK.UTF-8', 'sk_SK', 'sk', 'slovak')
    );

    $locale = key_exists($lang, $map) ? $map[$lang] : $map['en'];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    putenv('LC_ALL=' . $lang); // for windows and gettext
}
```

Usage:

```
setLocaleByLang('en'); // received from user preferences or browser accept header
```

I use [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) for updating .po files and translating.